# Rationale behind `delete` accepting a null pointer

Tags: c++

I would like to know the rationale behind the fact that `delete` accepts the null pointer. In C, `free` accepts the null pointer, but I believe that the rationale is the fact that a `malloc(0)` can return the NULL pointer and therefore, the NULL pointer can be considered in some way as a valid pointer (to a 0-sized array).

In C++, it seems that `new` is not allowed to return a NULL pointer. So I am puzzled. Do you have any code that looks better when using that fact that you can call delete on a null pointer ?

François

PS: I am teaching C and C++ and I would like to know if it is useful to teach C++ people that `delete` works on a null pointer. And if I do, I need to find some exercices where it is useful to do that.

Comment: One reason is shorter code `if (p) delete p;` simply becomes `delete p;`

Comment: If you have a class that holds a pointer that might or might not point at actual data, using a null pointer to mean "no data" is pretty common.

Comment: If you teach your students about move semantics, having `nullptr` to `delete` in destructor becomes fairly common. And there is a [noexcept version of `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow) that returns `nullptr`.

Comment: @PeteBecker : It is pretty common in the C/C++ world but not universal. It is a C exemple, but the GLib library does not accept null pointers (or at least emits a warning) for their free functions.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen : I agree that without exceptions, new can return a `nullptr`. This sounds to me the best reason.

Comment: Kate Gregory has a nice presentation ["Stop Teaching C"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk) for teachers of C++.

Comment: @InsideLoop -- you asked about C++; C examples aren't relevant. They are two different languages.

Comment: Compiling without exceptions puts you outside of the C++ standard; the rule that `delete` can take a null pointer has nothing to do with this non-conforming hack.

Comment: @PeteBecker : The problem is that the usage of null pointers is overloaded. For instance, if you use a struct node made of int key, node* left, node *right to design a binary tree, the null pointer means "empty tree" for many people. This is a valid tree and not something that should be considered as a "no tree" in some circumstances.

Comment: @InsideLoop -- as I said, a null pointer can be used to mean "no data". As in, no left node or no right node. And that's an example of when being able to delete a null pointer is useful: the 'node' destructor can simply delete the left and right pointers, without having to check for null pointers.

Comment: Let's turn this on its head: what would be better if `delete` *didn't* accept a null pointer.